# Trouble deleting a mail in Deleted Items folder

Tags: c++, mapi

I am trying to write an app that send and receive emails with MAPIEx.
I am able to send receive and even delete message from in box but when I try to delete the message from "Deleted items" folder it doesn't delete them.
I am using win7 64 version and outlook 14.07 (64 bit)

relevant code:

```
CMAPIFolder * folder = NULL;    
folder = m_mapi.OpenDeletedItems(FALSE);
if (folder){
    incoming_folders.AddTail(folder);
}

POSITION pos = incoming_folders.GetHeadPosition();
while (pos){
    folder = incoming_folders.GetNext(pos);
    if (!folder->GetContents()){
        delete folder;
        continue;
    }

    folder->SortContents(TABLE_SORT_DESCEND, PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME);


    while (folder->GetNextMessage(msg)){

        folder->DeleteMessage(msg);
        break; //tring to delete one mail



    }
    delete folder;
}
```

When I am debugging I get to the DeleteMessage line but nothing happens.
Any idea?

Comment: That does not look like Extended MAPI. What is the CMAPIFolder class?

Comment: // File: MAPIFolder.h
// Description: MAPI Folder class wrapper
//
// Copyright (C) 2005-2011, Noel Dillabough
class AFX_EXT_CLASS CMAPIFolder : public CMAPIObject
{
public:
 CMAPIFolder();
 CMAPIFolder(CMAPIEx* pMAPI, LPMAPIFOLDER pFolder, LPCTSTR szName=NULL);
 ~CMAPIFolder();

Comment: So as you step through that code, does it get executed successfully?

Comment: yes but the email stays at the trash folder...

Comment: Why not delete it from there?

Comment: i am opening the deleted files folder and try to delete it but it stays....
where do "there" refers to?

Comment: I refer to the Deleted Items folder. What is your code that deletes the message?

Comment: BOOL CMAPIFolder::DeleteMessage(CMAPIMessage& message)
{
 return DeleteObject(message);
}
BOOL CMAPIFolder::DeleteObject(CMAPIObject& object)
{
 ENTRYLIST entries={ 1, object.GetEntryID() };
 HRESULT hr=Folder()->DeleteMessages(&entries, NULL, NULL, 0);
 return (hr==S_OK);
}

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me. What do you see when you step through that code? Does DeleteMessages() return S_OK?

Comment: That is the weird thing, yes it does...

Comment: The more odd is that it works fine on outlook on win 7 32 bits